# CodeCademy Getting Started with Programming Javascript 26/28 Variables Error

Tags: javascript, variables

```
// On line 2, declare a variable myName and give it your name.
var myName = "Daniel";
// On line 4, use console.log to print out the myName variable.
console.log(myName);
// On line 7, change the value of myName to be just the first 
// 2 letters of your name.
myName = console.log(myName = myName.substring(0,2));
// On line 9, use console.log to print out the myName variable.
console.log(myName);
```

Codecademy tells me that I am incorrect, "`Oops, try again. Did you set myName equal to your name, like this: myName = 'Leng'?`"

However, I believe I have, and cannot find my error.

Comment: Take away the console.log() from the substring and it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, it was fixed. You replied so quickly, now I can continue my lesson! Have a good day! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the error might be on:

```
myName = console.log(myName = myName.substring(0,2));
```

I think it should be:

```
myName = myName.substring(0,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You assigned to `myName` variable `console.log` result, not substring.

So, line 7 should be:

```
myName = myName.substring(0,2);
```